# Does nodejs parse JavaScript before feeding it to V8?

Tags: node.js, v8

V8 does not understand things like "require" and "setTimeout", but Nodejs does. Hence, am I right that Nodejs has its own parser/interpreter, that identifies the non-js tokens and processes them before feeding the rest of the JavaScript to V8?

Comment: `that identifies the non-js tokens` Those are js tokens. Those are regular functions, defined by nodejs.

Comment: `setTimeout` and `require` are not part of the Javascript standard.

Comment: This doesn't make them non-js tokens.

Comment: @enanone Maybe they are not, but neither is for instance `readFileSync` or if you define a `function fooBar()` in your code. And still you can use them ...

Comment: Hence my question. Does Nodejs parse/interpret the JS code before feeding it to V8? To differentiate what is JavaScript from what is not (e.g. `setTimeout` and `require`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedders of V8 add embedder-provided functions (and/or other properties) to the global object. They can use V8's [embedding API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/include/APIDesign.md) to add features that are implemented in C++; they can also execute JavaScript files that define global functions and/or properties (just like you would in user-space). Node.js uses a combination of both techniques.

See [V8's docs](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) for an introduction.

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all, which is probably my fault. Assume that I pass the following line of code to the V8 engine: `setTimeout(() => console.log(0), 0)`. That would crash the V8 engine, wouldn't it?

Comment: @enanone No, it wouldn't. What Node.js does is essentially `globalThis.setTimeout = function(callback, timeout) { /* Some node-internal implementation */ }` before passing any scripts to V8. (Also, if V8 encounters code that looks like a call but what it's calling is not defined, it wouldn't crash, it would throw an exception.)

Comment: Crap, that makes sense. Thanks buddy. I guess the same holds for `require`? Or is that handled differently? EDIT: I just tested it, the same holds for `require` :)

Comment: It holds for everything that's not part of the ECMAScript standard and hence not implemented by V8 itself. In browsers that's the entire DOM interface.

Answer (score 2):

Node offers a "host environment", and as such provides global objects (including function objects) and hooks to the JavaScript engine. This does *not* involve parsing JavaScript. The ECMA Script specification focuses on the core language only, and specifically mentions that the capabilities of the host are out of its scope.

You can read about this in the ECMA Script specification, in chapter [4](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-overview). Here are a few quotes from that section -- but it is worth to read it in full:

> ECMAScript as defined here is not intended to be computationally self-sufficient [...]
>
> ECMAScript is now used to provide core scripting capabilities for a variety of host environments. Therefore the core language is specified in this document apart from any particular host environment. [...]
>
> To aid integrating ECMAScript into host environments, this specification **defers** the definition of certain facilities (e.g., abstract operations), either in whole or in part, to a source **outside** of this specification. [...]
>
> In other words, facilities that are host-defined are often further defined in external specifications. [...]
>
> A **host environment** is a particular choice of definition for all host-defined facilities. A host environment typically includes objects or functions which allow obtaining input and providing output as host-defined properties of the global object.

Comment: Assume that Nodejs does not parse JavaScript. If it does not parse JavaScript, it follows that it does not know that V8 cannot understand this line: `setTimeout(() => console.log("hi"), 0);`. If Nodejs would pass that line to V8, nothing would work, since V8 cannot understand that line. On the assumption that Nodejs does not parse JavaScript... how does it know that is should not pass the `setTimeout(...` line to V8?

Comment: Node defines the global object and objects like `setTimeout`. V8 -- like other JavaScript engines -- has several hooks with the host environment (Node in this case). See Appendix D in the ECMA Script specification, that is referenced in the chapter 4 I referred to. So that statement **is** parsed by V8, and V8 understands it because it has access to the objects that Node has defined.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it! I am voting the other answer as the right one because the other guy used a language that was vastly easier to understand (as in "I did not have to fight to get the answer out of him"), but your's is the correct answer as well (in case someone is reading the comments)